# How to regex replace paragraphs with less than 3 characters inside of them?

Tags: javascript, regex

So basically, I have this:

```
str.replace(/<p><\/p>|<p>\.<\/p>/g);
```

Trying to remove all paragraphs with nothing or less than 3 characters inside. The first part of the regex works properly, but the paragraphs like this: `<p>.</p>` don't get removed. Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: `\.` only matches the literal dot character. Is that what you want to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex. `/<\s*(p|P)[^>]*>([^<.]{0,3}|\..{1,2}|.{1,2}\.)<\s*\/(p|P)\s*>/g`
This will match a `<p>` tags, case-insensitive and the paragraphs can have different attributes.

Example:

```
var str = "<p>test</p><p>t</p><P>tes</P><p class=\"someclass\">s</p>< p >some long text</p>";
str.replace(/<\s*(p|P)[^>]*>([^<.]{0,3}|\..{1,2}|.{1,2}\.)<\s*\/(p|P)\s*>/g, '');
```

And a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tkwk5/3/

Comment: [^>] is matching everything except '<'. It's there to match the whole content different from closing tag. So [^<]{0,3} will match everything with length from 0 to 3 which doesn't contain '>'.

Comment: Ahh...just saw the rest of the question...I'll fix the regex in just a second. I'm sorry

Comment: It's fixed. Once again I'm sorry about my inattention.

Comment: Just one more thing. This is not working in case when you have a dot in string which is 3 characters or less. I'm working on a fix :-)

Comment: I've fixed the last issue. It should be now ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex.

```
<p>.{0,2}</p>
   ^ any character, 0 - 2 times (you said less than 3)
```

Escaping the `.` as `\.` matches a literal `.`.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/yQ5pu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to play with the tags, the browser provides an API for all of this that runs faster, less prone to bugs/exploits, and annoying "why's my browser freezing?" quirks.

```
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

That's it. Every tag in the page is now part of an array of document elements inside the variable pTags.

You can then inspect what's inside of any given pTags[i], and remove it via:

```
pTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(pTags[i]);
```

There are of course other ways to use [the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>[0-9A-Za-z]{0,2}</p>
```

any character or number between the paragraph {0,2} for less than 3 occurences.

Comment: "character" != "letter". A space is a character.